# Способ подсчета очков для вложенных документов в Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Есть ли какой-то механизм подсчета _score для вложенных документов?
Например, пользователь ищет "красная машинка"
В индексе есть документ "Машинка" в котором есть вложенности "красная" "синяя" "белая".
_score для документа родителя "машинка" условно будет 0.5 для вложенного документа "красная" 1, для вложенного документа "синяя" 0.5, "белая" 0.5
А если пользователь будет искать "розовая машинка", то у всех будет 0.5
такое  можно реализовать?

Мне нужно в зависимости от этих очков выводить ссылку на родительский документ или сразу на вложенный.